# How to OUT from a stored procedure using LAST_INSERT_ID()

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, return, command-line-interface, lastinsertid

Mysql Version 14.14 Distrib 5.1.41

I have a stored procedure that I am trying to get compiled but an error keeps cropping up. My stored procedure prepares an insert statement, executes it, deallocates the prepared statment and then attempts to return the last insert id. 
This is an pseudo extract:

```
1 CREATE PROCEDURE `audit`( IN pExampleValue varchar(50))
2 
3 BEGIN
4 PREPARE stmt FROM 'INSERT INTO `Audit` (`Value`) VALUES (?)';
5 EXECUTE stmt USING @pExampleValue;
6 DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt
7 
8 RETURN LAST_INSERT_ID() AS `AuditId`;
9 END$$
```

From what I am able to gather my version of mysql can used prepared statements in stored procedures. However the error I am getting is.

```
SQL Error (1313): RETURN is only allowed in a FUNCTION
```

As the error says I cannot return from a procedure. However I can out from a procedure? I'm having a difficult time finding examples of a query being OUT'ed, How exactly would I do that from this example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either, declare an `OUT` parameter, or make your procedure a `FUNCTION`.

You'll find sufficient documentation here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-procedure.html

Comment: After the out param is declared how do I put the last insert id in it. Is it as simple as SET @a = LAST_INSERT_ID()?

Comment: The simplest way: Replace `PROCEDURE` by `FUNCTION` and make line 8: `RETURN LAST_INSERT_ID();`

Comment: I don't think prepared statements can be used in functions, which is why I'm using a procedure. (Albeit it doesn't matter now because it seems like I can't used a prepared statement in a procedure if I am calling it from a trigger anyways, go figure)

Comment: Why do you need it to be a prepared statement? Just issue the insert query within the routine.

Comment: I'm a bit worried about security. I am getting some session variables from my php script by doing SET @username = $_SESSION['username'] and then passing that on to my procedure. So I wanted to prevent injection there if the session variables were hacked.

Comment: I don't know if that is a viable concern or not.

Comment: Assuming you use a statement of the form ``INSERT INTO `Audit` (`Value`) VALUES (pExampleValue)``, and you place this statement *within the body of the stored routine*, it is not possible for the contents of the variable `pExampleValue` to change the nature of the insert query. Even if it contains SQL-like text, it is still just a string and there is no way to pass in a string that will somehow break out of its bounds and become 'active' SQL. It is prudent, though, to execute your `CALL` statement using a prepared statement.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I needed to make sure. ^_^